# How to trigger an event on click of pagination in an dojo enhancedgrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I want to trigger an event and call a function on click of pagination in the grid.
My function should be call in some jsp where this grid is defined. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do? Do you mean a click in the Grid, on the Pagination Buttons? Regards

Comment: onClick of the pagination button, I want an event to be triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a store backing this up? If so, you can check to see when a fetch occurs on your store?